# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<br /> when using JSON parse on the response from AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, syntax-error

I'm making a dropdown with datefrom, and dateto, then display the dates between those, but it's not displaying and I keep on getting this error message, in the console.

```
VM652:1 
        
       Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<br />
<b>"... is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (<anonymous>:18:30)
    at c (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:28327)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:29072)
    at l (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:79901)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:82355)
```

Here is the script:

```html
<script>
  // Add an event listener for the form submission
  document.querySelector('#submit-button').addEventListener('click', function()  {
    // Prevent the default form submission behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get the selected values of the "fromdate" and "todate" dropdown menus
    var fromDate = $('#fromdate').val();
    var toDate = $('#todate').val();

    // Send the AJAX request to the PHP script
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "functions/search-sales_function.php",
      data: { fromDate: fromDate, toDate: toDate },
      success: function (response) {
        // Parse the JSON response
        var salesData = JSON.parse(response);

        // Loop over the sales data and insert it into the table
        for (var i = 0; i < salesData.length; i++) {
          var date = salesData[i]['date'];
          var sales = salesData[i]['total_sales'];
          $('#sales-table tbody').append(`
            <tr>
              <td>${date}</td>
              <td>${sales}</td>
            </tr>`
            );
        }
      },
    });
  });

</script>
```

and this the php file:

```php
<?php
    include "db_conn.php";
      // Get the values of the "fromdate" and "todate" dropdown menus
      $fromDate = $_POST['fromdate'];
      $toDate = $_POST['todate'];

      // Check the connection
      if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
      }

      // Write a SELECT statement to get the sales data between the selected dates
      $sql = "SELECT date, SUM(sales) as total_sales FROM sales WHERE date BETWEEN '$fromDate' AND '$toDate' GROUP BY date ORDER BY date ASC";

      // Execute the SELECT statement and fetch the results
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

      // Loop over the results and add a row to the table for each date
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $date = $row['date'];
        $sales = $row['total_sales'];
        echo "<tr>
                <td>$date</td>
                <td>$sales</td>
              </tr>";
      }

      // Close the connection
      mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

I want to display the the rows that have the dates between the chosen dates, but the error keeps on showing in the console log, and the table is not displaying

Comment: Your PHP responds with HTML so why are you trying to parse it as JSON?

Answer (score 2):

The error is related to response error of your ajax method. The code sent the result for `ajax` request. You should use `echo json_encode($data);` in your php file.

```
$data = [];
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $row;
        echo json_encode($data);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks David, what you mean is correct, my issue; there is a missing field in my view, just I corrected the query now it is working properly

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off php error deprecation notices.  I had this issue and it was because the PHP deprecation notice was getting picked up in the JSON ajax.

```
<br />
<b>Deprecated</b>:  Return type of Stripe\StripeObject::offsetExists($k) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in <b>/home/wiwt0111/staging.waihekeislandwinetours.co.nz/wp-content/plugins/gravityformsstripe/includes/stripe/stripe-php/lib/StripeObject.php</b> on line <b>202</b><br />
<br />
<b>Deprecated</b>:  Return type of Stripe\StripeObject::offsetGet($k) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in <b>/home/wiwt0111/staging.waihekeislandwinetours.co.nz/wp-content/plugins/gravityformsstripe/includes/stripe/stripe-php/lib/StripeObject.php</b> on line <b>212</b><br />
<br />
```

Turning off all error reporting solved this issue for me.

```
     error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

Answer (score -3):

I got this error while using Jquery.Fileupload script
I solved by downgrading my server php version to 8.0 when it was 8.1

Comment: The source of the problem in the code in the question is clearly the explicit HTML output from the PHP the OP wrote. What's more, they aren't using Jquery.Fileupload and its unlikely they were using PHP 8.1 since it was very new at the the time the question was asked.